# How validate a Reactive Form in Angular 10+ using two groups inside my formBuilder.group

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I need to validate my form with two diferents groups inside the main formBuilder.group. I don't know how get the value 'errors' is my HTML [ngClass].

component.ts:

```js
    creatFrom(): void {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      estimated: this.formBuilder.group({
        fieldDiff1: ['', Validators.required],
        fieldDiff2: ['', Validators.required],
        fieldDuration: [''],
        opDuration: ['', Validators.required],
        taxiInParameter: [''],
      }),
      realized: this.formBuilder.group({
        fieldDiff1: ['', Validators.required],
        fieldDiff2: ['', Validators.required],
        fieldDuration: [''],
        opDuration: [''],
        taxiInParameter: [''],
      }),
      taxiInParameter: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

component.html:

```html
     <div formGroupName="estimated">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3" [ngClass]="{'has-error':mF.fieldDiff1.errors && isSubmited}">
                            <label class="control-label" for="estimated_fieldDiff1"><span translate>Data</span>1*:</label>
                            <ng-select 
                                id="estimated_fieldDiff1" name="estimated_fieldDiff1"
                                formControlName="fieldDiff1"
                                [items]="fieldsEstimatedData1"
                                class="select-option" required>
                            </ng-select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below

```js
[ngClass]="{'has-error':myForm.get('estimated').get('fieldDiff1').errors && isSubmited}"
```

Or

for better understanding in ts file

```js
get estimateForm(): FormGroup {
   return this.get('estimated');
}

get realizedForm(): FormGroup {
   return this.get('realized');
}
```

```js
[ngClass]="{'has-error':estimateForm.get('fieldDiff1').errors && isSubmited}"
```

Comment: First of all thanks for spend yout time to aswer! I appreciate a lot. This works fine! I've made some adjustes in your code, like in get method of ts file.to return the value of the get method we need typeof with AbstractControl, and return this.myForm.get('realized').

get realizedForm(): AbstractControl {
    return this.myForm.get('realized');
  }